# Inserting a value into an indentity column db2

Tags: insert, db2, identity, db2-400

Hi I try to insert data from a script into a DB2 table which has an identity column. I read that using the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE ...
```

would work, but it doesn't. Here is the exact query:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.MYTABLE OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE (
     IDENTITY_COLUMN
    ,SOMEVALUE
    ,CREATEDTIME
    ,UPDATEDTIME
) VALUES (
     2
    ,'656566'
    ,'2012-07-12 16:25:34'
    ,NULL
);
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "VALUE" was found following "DE OVERRIDING 
SYSTEM".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Thank you!

Comment: The answer depends on the exact table definition and the DB2 version and platform, which you chose not to share with us. `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` clause seems to be valid only in DB2 for i.

Comment: However, IBM i uses 7 byte error codes (typically formatted AAAxxxx, 3 alpha & 4 digits (now hex)) so an 8 character error code comes from somewhere else.

Comment: @WarrenT This a perfectly fine Error code that you get when running the db2 command line code. The equivalent sql error code is -104.

Comment: @Peter Schuetze : Can you describe what you mean by "the db2 command line code" when discussing DB2 for i? I'm not aware of any "db2 command line" on i.

Comment: @user2338816 That is a perfectly fine error code in db2 LUW

Comment: @mustaccio: It's a standard SQL feature, see e.g. `ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) 14.11 <insert statement>`. Db2 being quite standards compliant, I don't think it matters which version and platform this is about.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Db2 for i, the clause is located *after* the column list, syntactically, [see the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-insert) as well as the SQL standard specification `ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) 14.11 <insert statement>`. So, write:

```sql
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.MYTABLE (
     IDENTITY_COLUMN
    ,SOMEVALUE
    ,CREATEDTIME
    ,UPDATEDTIME
) 
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE -- Put it here
VALUES (
     2
    ,'656566'
    ,'2012-07-12 16:25:34'
    ,NULL
);
```

Comment: This syntax `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` is available only on the Db2-for-i (as/400) legacy platform.  It is not available on either Db2-LUW or Db2-Z/OS at currently supported versions in 2021.

Comment: @mao: Yes, sure, but given that the mistake was a simple syntactic one, I suspect that it doesn't really matter in this case? As I mentioned, it's also the syntax as defined in the SQL standard, and at least PostgreSQL, H2 also support it.